# Add comment to youtube video

Tags: c#, asp.net, youtube-api, gdata-api

My webpage is developed in .net and i am trying to add comment to a youtube video using following code.

```
     string lsDeveloperKey = "myDeveloperKey";

    //This will ask user to login to accounts.google for posting comment
        if (!Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Contains("token"))
        {
            string lsUserName = "myusername";
            string lsPassword = "mypassword";

            YouTubeRequestSettings loSettings = new YouTubeRequestSettings(Keys.PortalName, lsDeveloperKey, lsUserName, lsPassword);
            YouTubeRequest loRequest = new YouTubeRequest(loSettings);

            Uri videoEntryUrl = new Uri(string.Format("{0}/{1}", Google.GData.YouTube.YouTubeQuery.DefaultVideoUri, "ofjQ_Gf5CQc"));
            Google.YouTube.Video loVideo = loRequest.Retrieve<Google.YouTube.Video>(videoEntryUrl);

            string lsRandomVideoId = getRandomId() + loVideo.VideoId;
            Session[lsRandomVideoId] = loVideo; ;

            Response.Redirect(AuthSubUtil.getRequestUrl(Request.Url.ToString() + "?v=" + lsRandomVideoId, "http://gdata.youtube.com", false, true));
        }

    //This will post a comment for logged user
        else
        {
            Session["token"] = AuthSubUtil.exchangeForSessionToken(Request.QueryString["token"], null).ToString();

            YouTubeRequestSettings loSettings = new YouTubeRequestSettings(Keys.PortalName, lsDeveloperKey, (String)            Session["token"]);
            YouTubeRequest loRequest = new YouTubeRequest(loSettings);

            Video loVideo = (Video)Session[Request.QueryString["v"]];

            Comment loComment = new Comment();
            loComment.Content = "This is my comment from my app";
            loRequest.AddComment(loVideo, loComment);
        }
    }
```

This code execute without any any error. It also posts comment if i log in with "myusername" & "mypassword".

But if i log in with any other user it give me following error:
E

```
Execution of request failed:
```

> https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/ofjQ_Gf5CQc/comments

```
 Stacktrace: at Google.GData.Client.GDataRequest.Execute() at
 Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.Execute(Int32 retryCounter) at
 Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.Execute() at
 Google.GData.Client.Service.EntrySend(Uri feedUri, AtomBase baseEntry,
 GDataRequestType type, AsyncSendData data) at
 Google.GData.Client.MediaService.EntrySend(Uri feedUri, AtomBase
 baseEntry, GDataRequestType type, AsyncSendData data) at
 Google.GData.Client.Service.Insert(Uri feedUri, AtomEntry newEntry,
 AsyncSendData data) at Google.GData.Client.Service.Insert[TEntry](Uri
 feedUri, TEntry entry) at
 Google.YouTube.YouTubeRequest.AddComment(Video v, Comment c) at
 YouTubeComment.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

I have worked a lot on this. I am not sure what wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using ClientLogin which is deprecated and may not work. Please consider using OAuth2 instead, here is an example: http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/trunk/clients/cs/samples/oauth2_sample/oauth2demo.cs. Also, YouTube will reject certain comments, try with a simple string with no special characters.